# NSSortDescriptor on a property's property of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My class structure looks like this:

```
TargetDetail : NSObject
@property Target *target


Target : NSObject
@property NSUInteger location
```

I have an Array of TargetDetail objects.  I want to sort them by the location.  I tried this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *byNum = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey@"target.location" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:byNum, nil];

[targetArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

My NSArray does not change. How do I use this method to sort?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sortedArrayUsingDescriptors does not sort the specified array in place, it creates a new array, sorts that, and returns that.
 So your code needs to be:

```
 NSArray *mySortedArray = [targetArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be loads more flexible if you use NSMutableArray. In this case you can use:

```
[targetArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

This will sort your array right in place. It's available since iOS 2.0